# Ext.get and update not working in IE

Tags: extjs

I can't get Ext.get to work in IE.  Works great in FF, Chrome and even Safari.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<select id="products" onchange="getReleases()">
    <option value="select">Select</option>
</select>
```

The Ext call is this:

```
...
success: function(response) {

    alert("response.responseText: " + response.responseText);
    Ext.get("products").update(response.responseText);          
}
```

I see results in my alert function.  What am I missing?

Comment: what does your `response.responseText` contains?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear as if this is an actual issue with Ext but an issue with IE.  You can see this by looking at the result of `Ext.get("products")` to a variable.

```
var result = Ext.get("products");
console.log(typeof result !== "undefined");
```

We can see from the log statement that it result is not undefined (Also, if it was undefined it wouldn't have been able to do the `update()`).

This is all assuming that the response.responseText was of the form `'<option value="select">Select1</option>'` which I think it was because you were getting it to work correctly in all browsers but IE.

Looks like it is a known issue with IE's select element's innerHTML property.  Following provides explanation and link for work around:

[Javascript - innerHTML not working with HTML select menus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738254/javascript-innerhtml-not-working-with-html-select-menus)

Here is a link to the MS bug: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/276228