# Script fails when populating a list in IE7, 8 and 9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a script that a friend wrote for me to populate numerous form fields with a list of dates from a text file. It calls the script once, and populates all fields with a particular Class name.

This is fine, and works perfectly in Firefox, Chrome, Safari and IE10. However the field appears blank (does not populate) in IE7, 8 or 9.

Any help anyone can give would be much appreciated. The code I'm using is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function() {
// call function to get list of options (call ONCE only)
var dateOptions = getDateOptions();

// get all elements with class tstselect and set the content to dateoptions
var els = document.getElementsByClassName('tstselect') ;
for (var i=0; i<els.length; i++) {
    if (els[i]) {
        els[i].innerHTML = dateOptions;
    }
}
};

function getDateOptions() {
var url = 'dates.txt?'+new Date().getTime()

var output = '' ;
var txt=false;
if (window.ActiveXObject){
    try {
        txt=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
    catch (e){
        try {
            txt=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch (e){
          alert(e);
        }
    }
}
else if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    txt=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else {
    return false;
}
txt.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (txt.readyState==4&&(txt.status==200||window.location.href.indexOf("http")==-1)){
        var mydates = txt.responseText.split('\n');
        for (var i=0;i<mydates.length;i++){
            if (mydates[i]) {
                // build up text string with all the options
                output += '<option value="' + mydates[i] + '">' + mydates[i] + '</option>' ;
            }
        }

    }
}
txt.open('GET',url,false);
try {
    txt.send(null);
}
catch (e){
}

return output; 
}
</script>
```

An example of the script in action can be found at: http://bespokebakery.co.uk/mailorder-birthday.html

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. where does it fail?

Comment: Part of your issue is `getElementsByClassName()`... http://caniuse.com/getelementsbyclassname

Comment: have you checked the IE dev tools to see if what errors are being thrown by javascript. (press F12 to get the dev tools window). Also, your link gives a 404 error.

Comment: Argh my fault, link is http://www.bespokebakery.co.uk/mailorder-birthday.html

Comment: Thanks canon, it should work in IE9 according that, but it doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

Hi innerHTML on select box will not work in IE. Kindly look into the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738254/javascript-innerhtml-not-working-with-html-select-menus). One of the answer in the link will give u the required solution