# Couldnt add option to combobox with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, combobox

I am trying to fill combobox with Javascript but I couldtn be able do it successfuly. This is very simple but I havent worked with Javascript for a long time.

Can anybody help me? here is my code...

```
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
var s=""
for(i=1;i<42;i++)
{
    s += '<option value='+i+'>'+points[i].musteri+'</option>';
}
document.getElementById('demo').innerHtml = s;
</script>
```

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for errors?

Comment: I couldnt see any error

Comment: try to console the html you are building if it is proper, also is var x = document.getElementById("demo"); is a select tag ??

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle of what you have so far? https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript - innerHTML not working with HTML select menus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738254/javascript-innerhtml-not-working-with-html-select-menus)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

innerHtml is not a "Select" element property in javascript.
You can add "option" like this:

```
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
for(i=1;i<42;i++)
{
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = points[i].musteri;
    option.value = i;
    x.add(option);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what browser you are using for test but I think you just simply missing ';' after

```
var s=""
```

and there is no **innerHtml** but it is **innerHTML** attribute for DOM.

This is the JSFiddle I used for test https://jsfiddle.net/ey9b3n2c/3/

Comment: this shouldn't affect the result because semicolons are optional in javascript.

Comment: I just think It would be best practice to do that all the time :-D